# VB.Net Visual Studio Error When Showing Form

Tags: vb.net

I get the following exception when showing a form:

> **InvalidOperationException was unhandled**
>
> Mixed mode assembly is build against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/2599/captureya.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/2599/captureya.png)

Dont really know why this isnt working. Any help?

Comment: I added the error message as text so that your question can be found from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the code for LoginForm. But I think you need to set an app.config flag to fall back to .NET 2.0 era bindings...

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

> First, what's a mixed mode assembly? A
>   mixed mode assembly is an assembly
>   that contains both managed (CIL) and
>   unmanaged (machine language) code.
>   Consequently, they are not portable to
>   other CPU instruction sets, just like
>   normal C and C++ programs and
>   libraries.
>
> Next, why use them? The primary
>   purpose for mixed mode assemblies is
>   as "glue", to e.g. use a C++ library
>   class as a base class of a managed
>   class. This allows the managed class
>   to extend unmanaged methods, allowing
>   the managed code to be polymorphic
>   with respect to existing unmanaged
>   functions. This is extremely useful in
>   many contexts. However, as something
>   like this involves extending a C++
>   class, it requires that the compiler
>   know all about the C++ compiler ABI
>   (name mangling, virtual function table
>   generation and placement, exception
>   behavior), and thus effectively
>   requires native code. If the base
>   class is within a separate .dll, this
>   will also require that the mixed mode
>   assembly list the native .dll as a
>   dependency, so that the native library
>   is also loaded when the assembly is
>   loaded.
>
> The other thing that mixed mode
>   assemblies support is the ability to
>   export new C functions so that other
>   programs can LoadLibrary() the
>   assembly and GetProcAddress the
>   exported C function.
>
> Both of these capabilities require
>   that the shared library loader for the
>   platform support Portable Executable
>   (PE) files, as assemblies are PE
>   files. If the shared library loader
>   supports PE files, then the loader can
>   ensure that when the assembly is
>   loaded, all listed dependent libraries
>   are also loaded (case 1), or that
>   native apps will be able to load the
>   assembly as if it were a native DLL
>   and resolve DLL entry points against
>   it.

[Source](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/mono/2008/Jan-27.html)

Comment: In your app.config.. It should be a part of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, tried the answer above and it did not work.

After much reading and trial and error and not finding anything that worked I noticed that I had both imported the Mysql dlls and added them in properties. After I removed the import statements it worked.

I know it was removing the import statements because I tested between every change I tried.

Hope that helps somebody.